# JQuery Datatables set checkbox to checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am currently using JQuery datatables to store information into and am populating it using a MD array.

But I want to by default set the check box property to `:checked` if conditions were met. I have tried various ways such as `.addclass` & `.addprop` to find any workarounds but I have not been able to get it working how I need it.

E.G So if value is disable do nothing, else if enable set the checkbox value to `:checked`.

I have attached a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kshrqoLm/1/) to replicate the issue I am having.

The code for that is then:

**HTML**

```
<table id="userTable" class="display" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Enable/Disable</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  data = [
    ['User_488', 'User 1', 'disable'],
    ['User_487', 'User 2', 'disable'],
    ['User_477', 'User 3', 'disable'],
    ['User_490', 'User 4', 'disable'],
    ['1000', 'User 5', 'enable'],
    ['1001', 'User 6', 'enable'],
    ['1002', 'User 7', 'enable'],
    ['1004', 'User 8', 'enable']
  ]

  var t = $('#userTable').DataTable({
    'columnDefs': [{
      'targets': 0,
      'searchable': false,
      'orderable': false,
      'className': 'dt-body-center',
      'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_check">';
      }
    }],
    order: []
  });

  function checkbox() {
    t.clear();
    if (data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var number = data[i][0];
        var name = data[i][1];
        var statustemp = "";
        var resarr = new Array(statustemp, number, name);
        if (status === "disable" || status == null) {
          t.row.add(resarr).draw(false);
        } else {
          t.row.add(resarr).draw(false);
        }
      }
      t.draw(false);
    }
  };
  checkbox();
});
```

Anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the `attr`:

```
'columns': [
    {
        "title": "Enable/Disable",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
            var checkbox = $("<input/>",{
                "type": "checkbox"
            });
            if(row[2] === "enable"){
                checkbox.attr("checked", "checked");
                checkbox.addClass("checkbox_checked");
            }else{
                checkbox.addClass("checkbox_unchecked");
            }
            return checkbox.prop("outerHTML")
        }
    },{
        "title": "Number",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
            return row[0];
        }
    },{
        "title": "Name",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
            return row[1];
        }
    }
]
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/kshrqoLm/3/)

Answer (score -1):

Order your data so you can give it to the datatable and then render the column based his value

```
jQuery(function($) {
  data = [
    ['disable','User_488', 'User 1' ],
    [ 'disable','User_487', 'User 2'],
    ['disable','User_477', 'User 3'],
    ['disable','User_490', 'User 4'],
    ['enable','1000', 'User 5'],
    ['enable','1001', 'User 6'],
    ['enable','1002', 'User 7'],
    ['enable','1004', 'User 8']
  ]

  var t = $('#userTable').DataTable({
    "data": data,
    'columnDefs': [{
      'targets': 0,
      'searchable': false,
      'orderable': false,
      'className': 'dt-body-center',
      'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
        if(data === "disable"){
            return '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_check">';
        }else{
            return '<input type="checkbox" checked class="checkbox_check">';
        }
      }
    }],
    order: [],
  });
});
```